# SQL Server queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

The search criteria should be based on any of the information available Reference No. [New / Old] and Site ID. For searching criteria at least 4 ~ 7 digits should be matched. For Reference ID last 7 varchar digits and for Site ID 4 numeric digits should be matched. What I should include in my query so that my requirements fulfill

```
String a = txt_search.getText();
String sql = "";

sql ="select * from account WHERE siteid ="+a+" or refrenceno='"+a+"' or oldrefrenceno='"+a+"' ";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: how please explain m in deep trouble

Comment: you should not use assignment operator (=) and use 'like' in place of '='

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like function to fulfill you requirements.

```
sql ="select * from account WHERE convert(varchar(50),siteid) like '%"+a+"%' or refrenceno like '%"+a+"%' or oldrefrenceno like '%"+a+"%' ";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write query like :

```
sql="select * from account where siteid like '"+a+"'"
```

You can put more conditions same as by adding 'or' logic.